# FPDF2 breaking url links that span multiple lines

Tags: python, pdf, text, fpdf2

When I convert text documents to pdfs in Python using the FPDF2 library it breaks apart urls that span multiple lines by adding a space or a newline (I'm not sure which one).

I use the following code to convert a text file to a pdf file using `FPDF2` library:

```
import glob
from fpdf import FPDF

#txt files
txt_files = glob.glob(path + r'\*.txt')       

for txt_file in txt_files:
    pdf=FPDF()
    doc=[]
    with open (txt_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
        print(txt_file)
        doc = infile.read()
        pdf.add_page()
        pdf.add_font("dejavu-sans", style="", fname="DejaVuSans.ttf")
        pdf.set_font(family="dejavu-sans", style="", size=12)
        pdf.write(5, doc)
        pdf.output(txt_file[:-4]+'.pdf')
```

My input text file looks like:
[image]

My generated pdf looks like this:
[image]

I use the `refextract` Python library and get this extracted reference:
[image]

At first I thought this was an issue with the refextract library but when I select the hyperlink in the pdf file it looks like the probelm is with FPDF2 breaking apart the url (hovering over the url in adobe only shows the partial address too):

[image]

Does anyone know how to overcome this so that nothing is inserted midway through a url when converting text files to pdfs using FPDF2?

P.S. Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to post the images within the post (i.e. not via links - it's not that I don't know how).

Comment: PS to add images use ![name](path)

Comment: @cards That only works if you have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: could you add the code of the `refextract`-part? It seems that the line-break is causing the problem. Did you encountered for others line as well?

Comment: I absolutely know that the break or newline character is causing the problem and that it's being introduced via the FPDF2 library when the  text to PDF conversion is happening.  Refextract is doing exactly what it is supposed to (in this case) which is why I didn't/am not posting that code. I can post it for interest but it's not at all relevant to the original post.

Comment: I am able to confirm that FPDF2 is inserting spaces when a url spans multiple lines and not a newline character. This makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to render text without performing any **wrapping**, you can use [FPDF.text()](https://py-pdf.github.io/fpdf2/fpdf/fpdf.html#fpdf.fpdf.FPDF.text):

```py
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font("Helvetica", size=14)
pdf.text(pdf.x, pdf.y, "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77930540/fpdf2-breaking-url-links-that-span-multiple-lines")
pdf.output("fpdf2-breaking-url-links-that-span-multiple-lines.pdf")
```